# Calculate the probability density function of $Y = 2 X + 3$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be normal with mean 1 and variance 4. Let $Y = 2X + 3$.

(a) Calculate the probability density function of $Y$.

(b) Find $P(Y \geq 0)$.

Comment: You can use the answer to (a) to solve (b). Or else, to solve (b), find $\Pr(X\ge -3/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

In order to answer this question you need to know 3 facts:

1. For a normally distributed random variable $X$, any random variable $Y=aX+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is normally distributed.
2. For some random variable $X$ with mean $\mathrm{E}[X]$, $\mathrm{E}[aX+b]=a\mathrm{E}[X]+b$
3. For some random variable $X$ with variance $\mathrm{Var}[X]$, $\mathrm{Var}[aX+b]=a^{2}\mathrm{Var}[X]$

Therefore, if $X\sim \mathcal{N}(1,4)$, $\mathrm{E}[X]=1$, $\mathrm{Var}[X]=4$ and therefore using the facts above we get: $$\mathrm{E}[Y]=\mathrm{E}[2X+3]=2\mathrm{E}[X]+3=2(1)+3=5 \\ \mathrm{Var}[Y]=\mathrm{Var}[2X+3]=4\mathrm{Var}[X]=4(4)=16$$

And therefore $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(5,16)$. You can then standardize this normally distributed random variable by subtracting $5$ and then dividing by $\sqrt{16}=4$, then using tables of the CDF of the standard normal distribution to answer the second part of the question.